# Proving inequality for positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

For a positive definite diagonal matrix $A$, I want to prove that for any $x$:

$$\frac{x^T \sqrt{A} x}{\|\sqrt{A}x\|_2} \geq \frac{x^T A x}{\|Ax\|_2}$$

So far I cannot find any counterexamples, and it intuitively makes sense since the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ operator should bring the eigenvalues of $A$ closer to $1$, but I can't prove this.

---

EDIT: changed $>$ to $\geq$

Comment: A potentially helpful observation:

Note that if $M$ is positive semidefinite, we have $x^TMx = \|\sqrt{M}x\|^2$.  Thus, we can rewrite your equation as
$$
\frac{\|A^{1/4}x\|^2}{\|A^{1/2}x\|} < \frac{\|A^{1/2}x\|^2}{\|Ax\|} \iff\\
\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|A^{1/2}x\|} < \frac{\|A^{1/2}x\|^2}{\|A^{1/4}x\|^2}
$$
with $B = A^{1/4}$ and $y = A^{1/4}y$, we can rewrite the above as
$$
\frac{\|B^3y\|}{\|By\|} < \frac{\|By\|^2}{\|y\|^2} \iff \|B^3y\|\,\,\|y\|^2 <  \|By\|^3
$$

Comment: Also, note that we fail to have strict inequality when $A = I$, for instance.

Comment: More thoughts that are insufficient for an answer: Since both sides scale with $\|y\|$, it suffices to consider the inequality in the case that $\|y\| = 1$.  That is:
$$
\|B^3y\| \leq \|By\|^3
$$
To that end: consider
$$
\min \|By\|^6 - \|B^3y\|^2 \quad \text{st} \quad \|y\|=1
$$
Let $f(y) = \|By\|^6 - \|B^3y\|^2$, and let $g(y) = \|y\|^2$.  We compute the Lagrangian
$$
2B^2(3\|By\|^4 I - \lambda B^4)y
$$
Now, $B$ positive definite.  So, setting the Lagrangian to zero yields
$$
(3\|By\|^4 I - \lambda B^4)y = 0 \implies \left(\frac{3 \|By\|^4}{\lambda} I - B^4\right)y = 0
$$

Comment: Applying the Hölder-von Neumann inequality yields
$$
\|By\|^2 = \operatorname{tr}[B^2yy^T] \leq 
\operatorname{tr}[B^3]^{1/1.5}\operatorname{tr}[(yy^T)^{3}]^{1/3}
= \operatorname{tr}[B^3]^{2/3}\|y\|^{2/3}
$$
which is close to what we're looking for, but not quite there

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your inequality says

$$\frac{\sum\sqrt{\lambda_j}x_j^2}{\left(\sum\lambda_j x_j^2\right)^{1/2}}\geq 
\frac{\sum\lambda_jx_j^2}{\left(\sum\lambda_j^2x_j^2\right)^{1/2}},$$
or after a simple transformation
$$\sum\lambda_j x_j^2\leq\left(\sum\sqrt{\lambda_j}x_j^2\right)^{2/3}
\left(\sum\lambda_j^2x_j^2\right)^{1/3}$$ 
And this is [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) with 
$p=3/2$ and $q=3$. The strict inequality does not always hold.